# How to change buttons from bootstrap3 to 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have been using this kind of button in bootstrap 3. Normally is the **Action** to update or modify  a row in a table.

I would like to use bootstrap 4, but this button is not rendering correctly.
I know this have changed, but how can I fix this?

This is the code for the button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: did you follow everything here? it gives you links to all the scripts you have to use also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: It might be because they dropped glyphicons in bs4 see 
 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/  component section

Answer (score 1):

Instead of glyphicons Bootstrap 4 recommends using font-awesome. You can read more about migrations [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components). While the migration documentation states that `btn-default` is now `btn-secondary`, to have your button rendered similarly to what you have now you want to use `btn-light`.

Here's what your updated code would look like with it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Here's the code in a working [codeply project](https://www.codeply.com/go/Z6erDAdqU4).

Answer (score 0):

From the migration page:
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

> Renamed .btn-default to .btn-secondary
>
> Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
>
> - the upstream version of Glyphicons
> - Octicons
> - Font Awesome